# send email with scrape data on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, smtp

I am trying to send some scrape data (output) in email body without attaching it in a file, but not able to do it. The data I want to send is:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.imd.gov.in/Welcome%20To%20IMD/Welcome.php').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

def message_to_send(soup ):
    article = soup.find('a', style='color:#000066;')
    title = article.text
    print(title)
    link = article['href']
    print(link) 

message_to_send(soup)
```

I want to add the above scrape data in email. I know SMTP and email library will be used, but I want to send the above contents. Does anybody have any idea how can it be possible?

Comment: What do you mean not attached? As a text in the body of an e-mail?

Comment: you can learn from this link: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

Comment: another suggestion, if you're using gmail, go to google account -> security -> less secure app access and then turn on access for less secure app access. otherwise you wont be able to send mails through gmail via smtp

Comment: Have a look [here](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/). Its so easy, you can basically copy paste the code.

Comment: @TimMironov ,yeah i want to send text in body of e-mail but not the usual text. I want the above scraped data in body which gets changed when new post/circular is available on the website and contents of new post as output in email body.